# Filter R Shiny Data Frame based on Slider range and display result in Data Table

Tags: r, shiny, slider

I'm new to R and R Shiny.  I'm currently trying to create an R Shiny app to display individual annual Mean Sea Level values in a Data Table over a selected period for a selected location.  The period is determined by the user selecting a start year and end year from a range slider, while the location is selected by the user from a drop down box.

Currently I'm just getting a bunch of html along side the drop down box and slider instead of a two column table showing the data for the selected period and location. See screenshot.  The period shown in the table should include the start year and end year selected by the user as well as the years in between, with their corresponding Mean Sea Level values shown in the adjacent column.

I realise it's probably an easy fix but being a novice I'm struggling.  I eventually want to also show a graph/plot for the selected data and also a trendline.  But for now I just want to get the filtered data showing in a table so I can expand the table to show some statistical information.

See my below code attempt.

Much appreciated

Bryan.

[image: Filtered Data Table fromRange Slider]

```
library(shiny)

Year <- c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010)
Auckland <- c(1760, 1549, 1388, 1967, 1326, 1765, 1814, 1693, 1502, 1751)
Wellington <- c(2176, 3154, 1138, 1196, 2132, 3176, 4181, 5169, 3150, 4175)
Lyttelton <- c(2176, 3154, 1138, 1196, 2132, 3176, 4181, 5169, 3150, 4175)
my_data <- as.data.frame(cbind(Year,Auckland,Wellington, Lyttelton))

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("New Zealand Annual Mean Sea Level (MSL) Summary"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Annual Mean Sea Level Summary for various locations around NZ."),

      selectInput("var", 
                  label = "Choose a Location",
                  choices = c("Auckland",
                              "Lyttelton",
                              "Wellington"),
                  selected = "Auckland"),

      sliderInput("range", 
                  label = "Choose a start and end year:",
                  min = min(my_data$Year), max = max(my_data$Year), value = c(2003, 2008),sep = "",)
    ),

    mainPanel(
      textOutput("DataTable")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$DataTable <- renderTable({
    MSL <- my_data[input$range[1]:input$range[2],]
    MSL},include.rownames=FALSE)

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do, `renderTable` in the server with `tableOutput` in the ui. you can also filter by the `Year` as in `my_data[my_data$Year >= input$range[1] & my_data$Year <= input$range[2],]`

```
library(shiny)

Year <- c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010)
Auckland <- c(1760, 1549, 1388, 1967, 1326, 1765, 1814, 1693, 1502, 1751)
Wellington <- c(2176, 3154, 1138, 1196, 2132, 3176, 4181, 5169, 3150, 4175)
Lyttelton <- c(2176, 3154, 1138, 1196, 2132, 3176, 4181, 5169, 3150, 4175)
my_data <- as.data.frame(cbind(Year,Auckland,Wellington, Lyttelton))

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("New Zealand Annual Mean Sea Level (MSL) Summary"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            helpText("Annual Mean Sea Level Summary for various locations around NZ."),

            selectInput("var", 
                        label = "Choose a Location",
                        choices = c("Auckland",
                                    "Lyttelton",
                                    "Wellington"),
                        selected = "Auckland"),

            sliderInput("range", 
                        label = "Choose a start and end year:",
                        min = min(my_data$Year), max = max(my_data$Year), value = c(2003, 2008),sep = "",)
        ),

        mainPanel(
            tableOutput("DataTable")
        )
    )
)
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$DataTable <- renderTable({
        dt <- my_data[my_data$Year >= input$range[1] & my_data$Year <= input$range[2],]
        dt[,c("Year",input$var)]
    },include.rownames=FALSE)

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Pork Chop.  How do I get it to show just the one location as selected by the user from the drop down list?

Comment: Thanks @Pork Chop.